# How to prefetch an image in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prefetch

I am trying to prefetch an image in my Angular app that sits within a Chrome plugin.

In the controller, I have:

```
$scope.nextlocation = 'http://i.imgur.com/Vzidbt4.gif';
```

In my view, I have:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="{{nextlocation}}">
```

When I load the page, I get an error saying:

```
GET chrome-extension://jlkgcdcdoooiaeamkhagpdolhgjgfgem/%7B%7Bnextlocation%7D%7D net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

When I hardcord the image in the doc, like below, it works fine.

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://i.imgur.com/Vzidbt4.gif">
```

How do I get this to work so that it dynamically updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://i.imgur.com/Vzidbt4.gif">
```

Change the above to:

```
<link rel="prefetch" ng-href="{{nextlocation}}">
```